# Powershell Get Parent Folder of a File

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a script which archives files for analysis.  My issue is that the file names aren't unique over multiple folders so they are being over written.

For instance:

```
C:\StuffToCopy\Folder1\myFile1.txt
C:\StuffToCopy\Folder1\myFile2.txt
C:\StuffToCopy\Folder2\myFile1.txt
C:\StuffToCopy\Folder2\myFile2.txt
```

At the end of my copy process I'm only getting 2 files, but I want 4.

I'd like the output to be like this:

```
C:\ArchiveCopy\Folder1_myFile1.txt
C:\ArchiveCopy\Folder1_myFile2.txt
C:\ArchiveCopy\Folder2_myFile1.txt
C:\ArchiveCopy\Folder2_myFile2.txt
```

Here's my script so far.

```
$files = dir -r -path "C:\StuffToCopy\" -i *.*

foreach ($file in $files)
{
    if ($file.LastWriteTime -gt (get-date).AddDays(-1)) {
        copy -path $file C:\ArchiveCopy\
    }
}
```

I want to do something like `copy -path $file.FolderName & '_' & $file C:\ArchiveCopy\`

I'm just not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 16):

If `$file` is really a file – an instance of `System.IO.FileInfo` (and not really a directory: `System.IO.DirectoryInfo`) then it has property `Directory` which is an instance of `DirectoryInfo` which has a `Name`:

```
$file |
  copy-item -destination { 
     Join-Path C:\ArchiveCopy\ -childpath ($_.Directory.Name + "_" + $_.Name) }
```

(Using a pipeline to start because the `-LiteralPath` parameter of `Copy-Item` will bind to the `PSPath` property from the pipeline, so no need to pull the original file's name from the `$file` object.)

If `$file` might be a directory, then you need to do more of the work yourself, but probably easier to filter out directories first:

```
dir -r -path C:\StuffToCopy\ |
  where { -not $_.PSIsContainer } |
  copy-item -destination { 
     Join-Path C:\ArchiveCopy\ -childpath ($_.Directory.Name + "_" + $_.Name) }
```

Note:

- No need to save all the file objects and then loop over them: let the pipeline do the looping
- No need to `-i "*.*"`: this is the default anyway (and if you need to filter files on a wildcard pattern prefer the `-filter pattern` parameter: the filter is passed to the filesystem rather than creating .NET objects and then filtering them which is much slower if there are a lot of files).

Answer (score 8):

Based on your script, here's another way to do this:

```
$files = dir -r -path "C:\StuffToCopy\" -i *.*
$destPath = "c:\ArchiveCopy\"

foreach ($file in $files)
{

   $folderPath =  Split-Path $file.fullname -parent
   $folder = Split-Path $folderPath -leaf
   $destFilename = $folder + "_" + $file.name
   $destFileFullPath = $destPath + $destFilename
   write-host $destFileFullPath
    if ($file.LastWriteTime -eq (get-date).AddDays(0)) {
        copy -path $file $destFileFullPath
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
dir -r -path C:\StuffToCopy | 
        where {!$_.psiscontainer} | 
        copy -dest { "C:\ArchiveCopy\$($_.Directory.Name)_$($_.Name)"}
```